# background limit

Tags: css

I reduced the graphics of a website so that it can fit 800px wide screen and it was set for 1000px before .I am done with resizing all the elements and have brought the site to the center of the page with 100px space on both the sides but the background is still repeating on the whole page .I want white space on the sides of the pages .bg.png is of size 100*100 and is repeating itself on the whole page .
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bmqk.png
The grey background need to be in 800px width.
The commands that I have used for background are :

```
    html {

    height:100%;
}
html, body, ul, form {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    background-image:url(../images/bg.png);

     margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;

}
body {
     background:url(../images/bgGeneral.png) repeat-x 0 0 ;width:800px;

     width:800px;
     margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by giving backgrounds both to `body` and `html`? They both overlap!

Comment: That was for header and it comes above the actual background ,I have removed it as I think it must not be cause of the problem .

Comment: Ha ha okay. Did my answer solve, anyways? By the way, Siddhu it would be good if you explain with a screenshot on what the problem is...

Comment: How can I add screenshots here Praveen??

Comment: Siddhu, you can't because of your reputation. You make a screenshot and upload to http://imgur.com and reply the URL in the comment.

Comment: http://imgur.com/zKyrf,ryv7y  ,bg.png is the main background and the other one has the header image .

Comment: Do you have a link of this?

Comment: No ,as you must have seen the grey background need to limit itself to 800px .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Suggestions

1. Giving the `HTML` a `width`, is of no use!

   ```
   html {
       width:800px;
       height:100%;
   }
   ```

   Give it to the `body` instead, keeping `html` normal! What are you trying to do?

   ```
   html {
       height:100%;
   }
   body {
       width:800px;
       height:100%;
   }
   ```
2. What does this mean? Remove these:

   ```
   html {
       background-image:url(../images/bg.png);

       margin-left: auto;
       margin-right: auto;

   }
   body {
       background:url(../images/bgGeneral.png) repeat-x 0 0 ;width:800px;
   }
   ```

   Margins do not affect HTML! Instead give this way:

   ```
   html {
       background-image:url(../images/bg.png);
   }
   body {
       background:url(../images/bgGeneral.png) repeat-x 0 0 ;
       width:800px;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
   ```

That should fix everything!

Answer (score 0):

Try    `background-repeat: repeat-y;`

It is repeating because you have set it to repeat-x